# How to access a field of class when there is a variable of the same name in current environment?

Tags: r, oop

Here is an example:

```
x = matrix("fromRData", 4, 4)
save(x, file="/tmp/x.RData")

TestClass = setRefClass("TestClass", fields = c("x"))
TestClass$methods(
    testfun = function(s) {
        load("/tmp/x.RData")
        print(x)
    }
)
TestClass$methods(
    initialize = function() {
        x <<- matrix("fromObj", 4, 4)
    }
)


myobj = TestClass()
myobj$testfun()

##      [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       
## [1,] "fromRData" "fromRData" "fromRData" "fromRData"
## [2,] "fromRData" "fromRData" "fromRData" "fromRData"
## [3,] "fromRData" "fromRData" "fromRData" "fromRData"
## [4,] "fromRData" "fromRData" "fromRData" "fromRData"
```

Obviously the `x` in the object is shadowed by the `x` in `/tmp/x.RData`.

Comment: Use `myobj$x`?... In the method you can use `.self$x`

Comment: Why not just to rename field and also you should avoid `load` to avoid all scope headache problems!

Comment: The names follow a naming convention in this project, I am not allowed to change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference `x` as `.self$x` within the method

```
x = matrix("fromRData", 4, 4)
save(x, file="/tmp/x.RData")

TestClass = setRefClass("TestClass", fields = c("x"))
TestClass$methods(
  testfun = function(s) {
    load("/tmp/x.RData")
    print(.self$x)
  }
)
TestClass$methods(
  initialize = function() {
    x <<- matrix("fromObj", 4, 4)
  }
)


> myobj = TestClass()
> myobj$testfun()
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
[1,] "fromObj" "fromObj" "fromObj" "fromObj"
[2,] "fromObj" "fromObj" "fromObj" "fromObj"
[3,] "fromObj" "fromObj" "fromObj" "fromObj"
[4,] "fromObj" "fromObj" "fromObj" "fromObj"
```

Comment: Nice. Another thing related, if I want to make changes to the x from x.RData using "<-" or "=", R would issue a warning. Is there is way to specify that the x I want to modify is not the class field, but the one in the current environment?

Comment: Good question. I would have thought assigning using `<-` or `=` would modify the variable in the current environment. You can probably ignore the warnings

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep a record here,
if you want to make changes to the x from x.RData using "<-" or "=",
R would issue a warning. In this case you can explicitly assign to
the x in current evironment:

```
e = environment()
e$x[2, 2] = "changed"
```